# Postion with flexbox in a responsive menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, flexbox, responsive

I have a Wordpress website, with my own theme, based on underscore.

I'm trying to learn flexbox.

And I have problems with my main menu, when adaptating it on mobile.

Here is my HTML:

```
<header id="masthead">

    <div id="site-branding"><!-- LOGO ---></div>

    <nav id="site-navigation">
        <button id="mainnav-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Mon bouton pour mobile</button>
        <div class="menu-menu-principal-container">
            <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav> 

</header>
```

And my CSS for wide website :

```
#masthead {display:flex; align-items:center;}

#site-branding {width:30%;margin-right:10%;}
#site-navigation {width:60%;}

#mainnav-toggle {display: none;}

#primary-menu {display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: baseline;}
#primary-menu li {list-style:none;}
```

So now, to adapt it for mobile, I did that :

```
#masthead {/*No changes*/}

#site-branding {flex-basis: 56.333%; max-width: 56.333%;}
#site-navigation { -flex-basis: 14.667%; max-width: 14.667%; }

#mainnav-toggle {display: block; }

.menu-menu-principal-container {display: none; }
.toggled .menu-menu-principal-container {display: block;}

#primary-menu {flex-direction: column;}
```

But something is missing.
.menu-menu-principal-container is not at the right place.

I want it to do like on this website for mobile : http://html.creativegigs.net/rogan/rogan-b/html/index-2.html.

I tried to understand the css of this website : can't manage to find the solution.

I tried with position : absolute on .menu-menu-principal-container

I tried so many things in facts.

But nothing work, And I'm guetting mad.

I'm sure the solution is easy, but that there is something I don't understand.

So please, any idea ??

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing a demo of the code, but if you've added `position: absolute;` to `.menu-menu-principal-container`, then `.menu-menu-principal-container`'s parent, `#site-navigation`, will need **relative positioning** ( `#site-navigation { position: relative; }` ) to make sure that its child doesn't get absolutely-positioned to somewhere else in the document.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found an answer....

Perhaps it could help someone else -

I just added left:0; and right:0; to .menu-menu-principal-container

I'm not sure how or why it is working.... But it is.